# NodeJS MySQL | Function returns wrong value from Table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, html, async-await

I got a project, where a function should Load a Value from a MySQL Table, but the value is always FFFFFF, even tho it should be other values. If I run the function loadSettings() manually, it spits out the right values

```
let mysql = require("mysql");
let con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: ""
});
let set = mysql.createConnection({
   host: "localhost",
   user: "root",
   password: ""
 });
let temp;
let temp2;
con.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
  console.log("MySQL: Connected to localhost!");
  let sql = "USE Abschlussprojekt;"
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
set.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("MySQL: Connected to localhost!");
 let sql2 = "USE Abschlussprojekt;"
 set.query(sql2, function (err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);
 });
});
async function dat2(Befehl) {
  set.query(Befehl, async function (err, result2) {
    if (err) throw err;
    await Sleep(10);
    //console.log(result);
    temp2 = result2;
  });
  return temp2;
}
async function dat(Befehl) {
  con.query(Befehl, async function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    await Sleep(10);
    //console.log(result);
    temp = result;
  });
  return temp;
}
let hs;
async function loadhighscore()
{
   return await dat('SELECT * FROM highscore;');
}
async function loadSettings()
{
  console.log("Reading from table settings...");
  return await dat2('SELECT * FROM settings;');
}
```

Main.js

```
let ohno = await loadSettings(); //new Variable
//await Sleep(100);
console.log("ohno=");
console.log(ohno);

while (ohno == undefined) { //Did the varibale load right?
  delete ohno;
  let ohno = await loadSettings();
  if (ohno != undefined) {
    console.warn("Ohno has the right type"); //Isn't undefined anymore, can continue and break out of loop
    console.log(ohno);
    haha = ohno; //Had to use a new one because ohno always undeclares itself
    break;
  }
  console.warn("ohno = undefined");
  console.log(ohno);
  await Sleep(1000);
}
await Sleep(100);
while (haha == []) { //Is the variable empty?
  console.warn("haha is empty");
  delete haha;
  let haha = await loadSettings();
  await Sleep(1000);
}
console.log(haha);
await Sleep(100);
if (haha[0].DarkMode == "true") {
  DarkMode = true;
}
else if (haha[0].DarkMode == "false") {
  DarkMode = false;
}
else {
  DarkMode = false;
  Fehler(2);
}


console.log('DarkModeColour: ' + haha[0].Farbe);
if (DunklerModusFarbe.indexOf("#") > -1) { // Ist # schon enthalten?
  DunklerModusFarbe = haha[0].Farbe;
}
else {
  DunklerModusFarbe = "#"+haha[0].Farbe;
}
```

So somehow it doesn't load the real values, it just loads FFFFFF out of anywhere but the table

[MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP5hi.png)

Comment: You can't compare arrays with `==`, as in `[1]==[1]` is `false`. Instead test `haha.length > 0` or something like that. You're also comparing to things like `"true"` which are strings, when presumably you'd want actual booleans like `true`.

Comment: This code seems really jumbled up. You're using `then` and `await` at the same time, when really you should be using `await` instead of `then`. You also have two connections for no apparent reason, doubling the amount of code you have here, plus some kind of wrapper around the query function which only serves to get in the way.

Comment: `ohno` doesn't "undeclare" itself. You've declared it with `let` as a scoped variable so it can't be used out of scope. If you want it to have a broader scope, don't redeclare it with `let` inside a narrower scope, just assign to it as-is.